# HangFire Database Tables

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, hangfire

I have an asp.net core web application using the ABP Boilerplate framework. I've implemented Abp.HangFire.AspNetCore HangFire into the application. The web application has a database for the application's data. And by default, the HangFire database tables were created in the same database where the application's data resides.

We were wondering about using a separate database for HangFire. Are there any implications in doing that? Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Change the db connection to your separate hangfire database in your host project.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("<name or connection string>", options);
```

Check out for more infos:
https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html

**Abp.HangFire.AspNetCore** reference only **Hangfire.AspNetCore** without Hangfire.SqlServer. In your Abp host project you could handle **Hangfire.SqlServer** like in any other ASP .NET Core (.NET 5) project.

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/511ed6389052b3850cb4c6b8d833fb192ec030ac/src/Abp.HangFire.AspNetCore/Abp.HangFire.AspNetCore.csproj